# Capturar valor de celda antes de añadir nuevo valor y realizar la suma en la misma celda Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

No soy muy experto en programación en Google Sheets y quería saber si hay alguna solución para lo que necesito. Actualmente en Excel tengo una macro que realiza lo siguiente:

- Captura el valor de la celda antes de ingresar un nuevo valor.
- Captura el valor nuevo en la misma celda.
- Realiza la suma de ambos valores y los arroja en la misma celda.

Quisiera saber si se puede realizar algo parecido en Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

En Google Sheets el "equivalente" a VBA en Excel es Google Apps Script. Puedes usar la grabadora de macros o bien crear to mismo el script.

La grabadora de macros la encuentras en ;

Herramientas y luego Macros y luego Grabar macro.

Para crear un script vinculado a tu hoja de cálculo:

Herramientas y luego en Editor de secuencia de comandos

Recursos

- [Automatizar tareas en Hojas de cálculo de Google](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7665004?hl=es)
- [Usar complementos y Apps Script](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=es)